# 403 Forbidden Error - iPage

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, hosting

I have an issue with my website, I linked it with Wordpress but there's a sub-menu where I get a 403 forbidden error.

[This is the folder in iPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8urI.png)

[And here's the Wordpress page I want to show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez5hK.png)

I tried removing the .htmaccess file and refreshing the permalinks but it didn't work at all.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Noo, Wordpress dont need any folders.
Wordpress works with the .htaccess

You can delete this folder and restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add any directories or files after WP installation is finished, all WordPress functions will work via administration panel. But let me explain what is going on.

The 403 forbidden error you are getting is normal and expected webserver behavior in your case.

The webserver checks the request (the URL given) and tries to determine if it is a file or a directory. In your case it is a directory, which (by default) makes your webserver serve index.html or index.php file inside that directory.
However, if no such file exists, the webserver's next step is to list all items in a directory, which you don't want and is disabled in your case (and in most web server's by default for security reasons), thus webserver returning 403 forbidden error.

You can try to add a file named index.html inside your directory and see what happens, the 403 forbidden error will be gone and webserver serve your file.

If you want to serve your WordPress page instead of the actual directory you have on the server, you will have to remove or rename the directory on your server, or rename the permalink for the WordPress page.